# Failed to load svg in packaged electron app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, electron, electron-forge

I am making an electron application that runs on **React, Webpack and Typescript**.
I am using **electron-forge** as a packaging/distribution tool and have no trouble during 
development. However during production it fails to load the image assets.

Down below you can find my Webpack config files, project structure and package structure.

[image: production-console]
[image: package-structure]
[image: project-structure]
[image: webpack-main]
[image: webpack-rules]
[image: webpack-renderer]